# Marginal Probability of Joint Uniforms

Tags: probability

I'm having trouble with the following problem:

Let $X_1$ be chosen uniformly on $(0, 1)$, let $X_2$ be chosen uniformly on
$(0, X_1)$, and let $X_3$ be chosen uniformly on $(0,X_2)$. Find the joint
density of $X_1$, $X_2$, and $X_3$ and the marginal density of $X_3$.

I have the joint: $1/(X_1X_2)$ on the domain $0<X_1<1;0<X_2<X_1;0<X_3<X_2$

But the marginal escapes me. I know the answer is $ln(x_3)^2/2$ on $0<X_3<1$. How do I get here though?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you do to get the marginal pdf of $X_3$?You just integrate out $X_1$ and $X_2$ between the limits 
thus as you can clearly see from the ranges of $x_1,x_2,x_3$ its quite clear Thus 
$$f_{X_3}(x_3)=\int_{x_3}^1\int_{x_2}^1 \frac{1}{x_1x_2} dx_1dx_2\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0<x_3<1$$
$$=\int_{x_3}^1\frac{1}{x_2}(log1-logx_2)dx_2$$
$$=\int_{x_3}^1\frac{-logx_2}{x_2}dx_2$$
$$\int_{logx_3}^0-mdm\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;using\;\;\;\;\ logx_2=m$$
$$=\frac{(logx_3)^2}{2}$$
Thus $$f_{X_3}(x_3)=\frac{(logx_3)^2}{2}\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0<x_3<1$$

Comment: Could you discuss why you used these bounds for $X_1$ and $X_2$? When I set it up initially, my integral for $X_2$ went from 0 to $X_1$ and $X_1$ went from 0 to 1 (as per the description for the bounds). Of course I got an ln(0) so I got stuck.

Comment: For the limit just draw the lines..and use the fact the $x_1\gt x_2$ from the graph..and for $x_3\lt x_2 \lt 1$.

Comment: Also why doesn't the upper bound on the outer integral stop at $X_1$? Isn't $X_2$ confined between $X_1$ and $X_3$?

Comment: It doesnt stop at $X_1$ because $x_2$ is always greater than $x_3$ and for the probability you integrate till 1..

Comment: I see that $X_2$ is greater than $X_3$, I don't see why it goes all the way to 1 at the top. Could you elaborate? These bounds are what are messing me up in this problem.

Comment: Okay let me give you a another line of thought..when you want to get the pdf of $X_3$ what do you need after you integrate $x_1$ and $x_2$.? You should have only $x_3$ left in the pdf isn't it?.the outer integral goes from $x_3$ to $x_1$ you would have an $x_1$ lingering somewhere in the pdf of $x_3$..which you obviously dont need or do you??...the absolute limit for $x_2$ is $1$ because that is mathematically correct and secondly you need a definte integral not just the antiderivative

Comment: Okay: suppose instead I want to marginalize on X1 -- what then should be the bounds?  (I did this, I just want to check if I understand)

Comment: First of all you why do you need to marginalise $x_1$ when its already given that it follow $U(0,1)$ but still you can get it if you integrate out $x_2$ and $x_3$ limits for $x_3< x_2 <x_1$  and $0 <x_3 <x_2$...

Comment: When I tried to do this integral, it didn't work though -- try writing it out. When you integrate out one variable, it gets reintroduced in the next integral. I thought it was X1 < X2 <1 and X2 < X3 < 1  -- but, as you pointed out, the result should integrate to 1, which it doesnt.

Comment: i suggest you please try to study multivariable calculus and specially double and triple integrals and change of order of integration .Then youll probably get your answer easily